# Assign unique value to each of local group

Tags: sql, hive

My sample input table is:

```
x y
1 a
3 b
5 b
4 a
2 a
6 b
```

I would like to get this:

```
x y z
1 a 1
2 a 1
3 b 2
4 a 3
5 b 4
6 b 4
```

First of all rows have to be sorted by `x` and then each local group of values in `y` should receive its unique number (example in `z`). In the end I would like to partition by `z`. I could not came up with query, despite the fact that operation seems to be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `lag()` and then a cumulative sum:

```
select x, y,
       sum(case when y = prev_y then 0 else 1 end) over (order by x) as z
from (select t.*,
             lag(y) over (order by x) as prev_y
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Your solution is great for small amount of data, but it think that it slows down my query (i am using Hive) on big sample because whole data has to be ordered in "one place". In fact `z` has to be unique only in scope of the same value of `x`, so maybe this knowledge could be used to optimize this query somehow?

Comment: @Cob . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  You should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: You are right. I was not clear enough. However, I think that I solved my problem with "PARTITION BY".